# Не получается настроить ЧПУ Yii2

Tags: yii2, чпу

В файле web.php настройки 'urlManager' последнее правило не применяется к url типа http://yii2/default?view=about не понимаю в чём ошибка.

.htaccess в корне проекта выглядит таким образом

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(web)
RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ /web/assets/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ web/css/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ web/js/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ web/images/$1 [L]
RewriteRule (.*) /web/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /web/index.php
```

.htaccess в папке web

```
 RewriteBase /

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

 RewriteRule . index.php
```

Настройка в файле web.php в папке config. baseUrl указан с данным значением

```
 'components' => [
    'request' => [
        'baseUrl'=> ''
    ],
 ]

'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'enableStrictParsing' => false,
        'rules' => [
            '<action:\w+>' => 
'news/<action>',
            '<action:\w+\W\w+>' => 
'news/<action>',
            '<action:\w+\W\w+>' => 
'news/default?view=<action>' - та самая настройка, нерабочая
        ],
    ],
```

Подскажите люди добрые что я делаю не так.

В контроллере страница возвращается не при помощи `actionDefault`, а

```
function actions(){
    return [ 
        'default' => [
            'id' => 'about',
            'class' => 'yii\web\ViewAction',
            'viewPrefix' => 'default'
          ]
    ];
}
```

Comment: Приветствую! Если правило не срабатывает, то скорее всего из-за того, что нет подходящих паттернов в rule. Попробуйте для **default?view=about** обозначить более конкретное правило. Например: "default" => "news/default". Принцип, слева uri в браузере (site.ru/ **default** ), справа путь: контроллер/действие.

Comment: Уже лучше показывается сообщение в браузере The view file does not exist: C:\OpenServer\OSPanel\domains\yii2\views\news\default/index.php. Как теперь указать на конкретный файл? В urlManager указал 'default' => 'news/default'

Comment: Ну ошибка говорит, что система не может найти view файл. Какое правило в итоге добавили?

Comment: В urlManager указал 'default' => 'news/default'

Comment: Ок. У вас видимо что-то с путём до view не так. Попробуй для 'viewPrefix' => '' указать пустые скобочки или null.

Comment: не работает, просто понятно что если сделать отдельный actionAbout всё будет работать как надо, но хочется разобраться как настроить ЧПУ когда страница возвращается при помощи метода actions().

Comment: Папка с view должна называться так же как и префикс. Т.е. в вашем случае в папке views должна быть папка default, внутри которой должен быть index.php. [Вот гляньте отрывок в книге](https://books.google.ru/books?id=QdpOCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA33&lpg=PA33&dq=Set+the+viewPrefix+attribute+of+the+ViewAction&source=bl&ots=diM5qlNKbK&sig=ACfU3U2IqKLxqkGe9EGuq1k2bALVIbBVDg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiX8pCK_9biAhUt_CoKHRvADJ4Q6AEwAHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=Set%20the%20viewPrefix%20attribute%20of%20the%20ViewAction&f=false)

Comment: то-есть вложенности не должно быть? у меня получается views/news/default
По сути это то же самое что и в книге, то есть prefix в actions указывает на папку default

Comment: Если память не изменяет, то могут быть и вложенности. Попробуйте и так и так.)) В одну директорию один файл, в другую другой, с другим текстом и проверьте.

Answer (score 0):

```
Теперь при обращении к url http://yii2/about получаю нужную страницу по пути корень_сайта/views/news/default/about.php
Запись в контроллере     
    function actions(){
        return [
            'about' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\ViewAction',
                'viewPrefix' => 'default',
                'defaultView' => 'about'
             ]
        ]
     }
в urlManager по этому запросу регулярка не потребовалась
```